# Error: Self message 'link-break' received when AckingMac is down when running multiple simulation in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I need to record statistic results of simulations, so I run in CmdEnv multiple simulations, I have this error: 
Error: Self message 'link-break' received when AckingMac is down

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with running several simulations, rather that one of the simulations follows a trajectory (based on it's initial seed) where this condition occurred. If you can find out which in which run actually this happens, you can start only that single run and you would still receive the same error. Obviously, this will not fix the error, but you have to debug/fix that particular run.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem occurs in the following run : Preparing for running configuration PATH, run #7...
Scenario: $0=100, $repetition=7
Assigned runID=PATH-7-20190710-15:58:38-3097
 But I don't know how to run and debug only this particular run

Comment: In the Launch Config dialog (Run | Debug Configurations menu) there is a 'Run(s)' text line where you can specify the run number (7). That will add a `-r 7` option to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nodes reaches the shutdown capacity, so I solved my problem by increasing the energyStorage.nominalCapacity.